# msiexec: Default to "do not close application" in silent mode

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I want to install my program with a quiet msiexec command such as:

msiexec /i file.msi /qn

However, if the application happen to be running, it will default to closing the application. I want msiexec to default to *never* close the application, but instead install on next reboot.

Is this possible as a command line option or through how the msi is built in wix?

Edit: I am installing a service btw

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [REBOOT property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371101%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You probably want to add `REBOOT=R`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, and also /norestart, but still it restarted the service (same for an application).